# Are questions about (minor) plot points in mundane settings on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There is a question on main which asks [how long a scent can remain tracable](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/how-long-scent-remains-in-air).

[image]

I personally feel like this question is off-topic since there seems to be no reason why this question couldn't refer to a mundane, real life scenario. There is nothing for us to add that [chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) couldn't do better.

I'm not 100% sure though and feel like it's valuable to discuss these edge cases more explicitly, so we can make a more confident decision the next time around. I'm also not entirely sure if this specific question could be rewritten to be more on-topic.

How does the community feel about this question?

Answer (score 4):

[The help center article we are working on](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/215/9) has this.

> For example, questions are **welcome** that are about:
>
> - Creation of elements of a world (languages, species, buildings, etc.)
> - Specific effects of events or world elements on that world's society, cultures, and environment
> - Technology and magic
>
> as long as they are **not about:**
>
> - Specific actions of individual characters, rather than the world they inhabit
> - Specific character building
> - General writing or storytelling (consider the [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) or [Role-playing
>     Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites)
> - Software that doesn't directly relate to worldbuilding (consider the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Software
>     Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange
>     sites)

1. This is about the specific actions of characters.
2. This is about storytelling and plot.
3. This is about something tiny in scale. ^
4. This is about something based in science in real life that is a perfectly reasonable [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) question.

^ I know we consider all scales, but this is small in impact as well as in physical size.

Therefore **off-topic**.

*To make on topic?*
I agree that this particular question can't be made on topic. It hits too many trigger for not being WB, albeit just.

Comment: I will add one comment here.  We did discuss during the definition phase that world altering characters WOULD be on topic.  I realize that is not the case with this question but I want to ensure that exception is out there.  Think Jesus, or Alexander or Plato or Elminster, or that prophet guy whose name I forget from Warcraft.  These people are forces of nature in a way.

Comment: I think that gets covered by "Specific effects of events or world elements on that world's society, cultures, and environment", but yes, good clarification.

Comment: I think as pointed out by Monica the question can be made on topic, basically by turning it the other way around. *As it stands* the question is a very poor fit here, but is likely possible to turn into a decent question on one of the science SE sites. (I'm not sure which one would be the best fit.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's off-topic because it's not about the *world*.  I don't think its being a small detail is the issue; worlds are made up of small details and it should be ok to ask about them.  But this doesn't seem to ask about *building a world*.

A question that asked "I want smells to be able to linger for several months; what properties of my world would cause that?" or "if it's implemented by X, what other properties would that have?" would be about the world and thus on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is off topic for a number of reasons:

1. It's not speculative - as you say a "grounded in reality" site can answer it
2. It's too small scale - world building can theoretically cover things as small as a village or building but this just feels too small
3. It's not about building a world, it's about research for a plot point within a world.

I agree it's definitely in the gray area though. It's not completely off topic, but I think it is enough off topic that it crosses the line.

I don't think this question can be re-written to fit as there is no way to make it about shaping the world. The question isn't asking about the world-shaping effects of lingering smells, or how to change how long they linger for, or even about the effects of scent on creatures. It's asking for a simple real-world forensics figure.

Comment: I agree, especially point 3 seems to be crucial, how this plot point is handled won't shape the world the story is set in.