# What exactly do we mean by "technology and magic" in the on-topic subjects list?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic

We have discussed before [what we should have in our "on-topic" help center page](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/215/29). I want to draw the community's attention to one of those bullet points.

Specifically, that post says that we welcome questions that are about:

- **Technology and magic**

*Just what do we really mean by that?*

As it stands, it seems to me to risk allowing pretty much anything. Can we narrow this down at least a little?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different variant (different enough I posted it separately for now):

- Technology and Magic where it is relevant to how the world works, but not where it relates to specific characters or plot elements.

Comment: Isn't that covered by the help article where it has:
(BULLET POINT!)Technology and magic.
(NEW SECTION)
as long as they are not about:
(BULLET POINT!)
    Specific actions of individual characters, rather than the world they inhabit

Answer (score 4):

Yes, let's make that bullet point instead read:

- Technology and magic, as they affect the world itself including elements and events of that world.

(I'm marking this Community Wiki. Feel free to edit to improve the wording, but let's keep the gist intact. Specifically, if you have alternate proposals, post those as separate answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

- The level and workings of technology and magic shaping the general structure and appearance of a world as well as general abilities and restrictions of its inhabitants.